# Error in HTML5WebView

Tags: android, webview, html5-video

I am working to play a video fron JW Player. So I am using HTML5WebView. Every thing else is fine. Just have 1 problem in custom_screen.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/error_console"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

> **Error Message:** No orientation specified, and the default is
>   horizontal. This is a common source of bugs when children are added
>   dynamically.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution.

Just add this line in the code: android:orientation="vertical"

Now the code will look like:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/error_console"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```